# Twig Template Layout Yii2 Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, twig, yii2

I want to set a layout like main.htm for all of my twig files in yii 2, but it loads the folder that controller call first, so I can not call my layout with extends.

in SiteController

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    return $this->render('index.htm');
}
```

This code calls views/site/index.htm

In my index.htm

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
```

So if I put the main.html in site folder, there is no problem, but I want to put it in the layout folder and can be called every controller views .. How can I do that ??

```
views
->site
  ->index.html
->layouts
  ->main.html
```

For example in symfony we can call like this

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

But in Yii2 I can not found a way to do this ....

I have done this with hardcoded the file viewRenderer.php. This is not the way I like it because a composer update the changes are gone away...

Now the function init is like this the loader is null here. I have added loader for my layouts.

```
$this->twig = new \Twig_Environment(null, array_merge([
        'cache' => Yii::getAlias($this->cachePath),
        'charset' => Yii::$app->charset,
    ], $this->options));
```

After adding a loader ..

```
$this->loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'\views\layouts');
```

And last thing is render function in ViewRenderer.php

```
 public function render($view, $file, $params)
{
    $this->twig->addGlobal('this', $view);
    //$this->twig->setLoader(new TwigSimpleFileLoader(dirname($file)));
    $this->loader->addPath(dirname($file));
    return $this->twig->render(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME), $params);
}
```

I want it without hardcoded changes in the core file of yii2-twig ....

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/3907

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a full path here `{% extends "main.html" %}`. Something like `{% extends "\layouts\main.html" %}`

Or even `{% extends "@app/views/layouts/main.html" %}`

I have not used twig with yii, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Yes I have tried them all, if you use full path just add after site folder like this and gives error again. like site/\layouts\main.html or site/@app/views/layouts/main.html. Because twig template loader folder define as the controller view folder in viewRenderer.php ...